# How ACTION data is send to REDUCER in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have made an counter app and using redux for state management, and working fine but i am confuse that how reducer function is getting the action data even we have not imported action function in reducer file.

Using following Architecture:

[image] [image]

Here is ACTION file code:

```
export const inc = () => {
   return{
       type: "INCREMENT"
   }
}

export const dec = () => {
    return{
        type: "DECREMENT"
    }
 }
```

and Here is reducer file code:

```
const InitialState = 0;

const changeNumber = (state = InitialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case "INCREMENT": return state + 1;
        case "DECREMENT": return state - 1;
        default: return state;
    }
}

export default changeNumber;
```

Reducer file function have to two parameters `state and action`. Where current state value is `0` and action value is an `object` which is coming from action file but how?

and as you know also having store white hold the global state and using redux official document for this.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `store.dispatch(myAction)`, `store` then goes to call the reducer with `reducer(lastState, myAction)`, takes the result of that and makes that result the new state.

If you have used `configureStore` or `combineReducers` to combine multiple reducers into one, every action is sent to every reducer in there.

Generally: as you are talking about an "actions file" and using string types I want to make you aware that you are probably learning a very outdated style of Redux. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic, createStore or connect and is only 25% of the code you are writing right now. To learn modern Redux, please follow the official [Redux Essentials Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Even if you want to learn old-style Redux, you are probably still following outdated documentation since we do not really recommend "actions files" or "action folders" any more. In case you want to learn old-style Redux, I would recommend you to follow the official [Redux Fundamentals Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview). But per default, go for modern Redux. It is the official recommendations since 2019.